# How to relay bindings from a Parent element to a Child element's data context?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a scenario where I have user controls on TabItem of a TabControl in the view. These user controls are individually bound to separate objects in the ViewModel. What I need is these controls to pass through to their bound object, the IsSelected property value of the parent TabItem.

Any ideas on how to do this kind of relay binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have your `ParentViewModel` track the `SelectedIndex` of the TabControl, instead of tracking individual `IsSelected` values?

If that doesn't work, usually I use something like Microsoft PRISM's `EventAggregator` or MVVM Light's `Messenger` to broadcast messages to other interested ViewModels.

In this example, I would still bind the `SelectedIndex` to something in the `ParentViewModel`, and anytime that changes I would broadcast a `SelectedTabChanged` message. The individual child ViewModels that are interested in such information would subscribe to these messages, and perform whatever logic was needed based on if the selected tab is the one they belong to.

Comment: I do have the SelectedIndex bound however, my ultimate need is to know when the particular controls and hence the underlying bound object know it is on the current selected tab or even know what their selected tab index is...I want this information in the view model so that I can prune processing to only those objects that are bound to currently user viewable controls, i.e. those controls that are on the selected tab.

Comment: @Jim Usually I keep an `ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Tabs` in my ParentViewModel, so my `SelectedTab` is an object instead of an int. Then when I pubilsh a `ChangeTabEvent`, I can pass the selected tab along as a parameter, so tabs that subscribe to that event can see if they equal the parameter. If so, they're selected. The other alternative is to put an `IsSelected` property on your child viewmodels, and have the `ParentViewModel` set that value whenever the `SelectedTabIndex` changes

Comment: @Jim as a side note, by default each TabItem in a WPF TabControl gets unloaded when it's not visible. So you could also hook into the Loaded/Unloaded events of the TabItem's content and set the `IsSelected` property of the DataContext.